# Agrupar los datos de un array de una consulta SQL según un campo especifico. (Laravel 5.6)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, foreach, orderby

Bien, no se como explicar este problema que tengo.

Tengo una vista en la que deseo mostrar los datos del dia de hoy de una tabla llamada `CitaMedica`

Dicha tabla, tiene un campo llamado `Especialidad`, lo que quiero hacer, es que me imprima como pequeñas tarjetas parecidas a estas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero, necesito que las agrupe en un div, dependiendo de la especialidad y es aqui donde me surge el problema.

En mi consulta, estoy usando el `OrderBy` para ordenarlo alfabeticamente, esto hara que todas las especialidades del mismo nombre se agrupen, aunque al final la consulta me devolvera una sola variable que almacenara *Todas las citas medicas* solo que ordenadas.

```
$fichasMedicasHoy = DB::table('fichamedica')
        ->join('Pacientes','fichamedica.Paciente_ID','=','Pacientes.ID')
        ->join('Medicos','fichamedica.Medico_ID','=','Medicos.ID')
        ->join('Especialidades','Medicos.Especialidad_ID','=','Especialidades.ID')
        ->select('Pacientes.nombre','Pacientes.apellidos','Especialidades.especialidad')
        ->where('fichamedica.fecha','=',$fecha_actual)
        ->where('fichamedica.turno','=',$turno)
        ->where('fichamedica.CentroMedico_ID','=',$Centromedico_ID->ID)
        ->orderBy('Especialidades.especialidad','asc')
        ->get();
```

En lo que necesito ayuda es en como controlar en la vista, que cuando el `foreach` recorra el array identifique cuando cambia de especialidad para que cree un div nuevo y ponga en ese nuevo div todas las citas medicas de esta nueva especialidad, y cuando vuelva a cambiar cree un nuevo div y asi sucesivamente, para poder mostrar todas las citas medicas de hoy, solo que en grupos, y estos grupos dependerán de las especialidades.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi vista tengo algo así, si se fijan, muestra el paciente y al lado la especialidad. Lo que necesito es que cuando cambien de especialidad, lo que haga por ejemplo, sea cambiar de color el fondo, en lugar de rojo un azul.

```
@foreach ($fichasMedicasHoy as $Paciente )
      <div style="background:#f4c1c6; margin:10px;">{{  $Paciente->nombre.' '
                                                       .$Paciente->apellidos .' ---- '
                                                       .$Paciente->especialidad }}
     </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Podrías subir tu código y sería mas sencillo ayudarte. Por la idea que se toma, puedes usar `groupBy('especialidad')` despues de que ejecutas el query para agruparlos segun especialidad, esto hara que debas hacer uso de foreachs anidados.

Comment: Actualice un poco la pregunta. Como seria eso de las foreachs Anidados?

Comment: Creo que lo que debes hacer es crear una nueva columna en tu tabla `Especialidades` llamada `color`. Y si no lo quieres hacer así, puedes almacenar esos colores como constantes, pero esos valores deben estar definidos, para guardar consistencia en tu aplicación. Posterior a eso, simplemente harías `style="background-color:{{ $paciente->especialidad->color }}"`

Comment: Bueno, eso seria una opción para lo de los colores, pero en realidad, lo que quiero hacer es algo asi como una agrupacion de Pacientes, por cada especialidad de un grupo de especialidaddes.
Lo que quiero mostrar en mi vista, es una tabla diferente, por cada especialidad.

Comment: Y por qué no usar Eloquent. Tal y como lo dices, simplemente bastaría con hacer `Especialidad::with('fichamedica.pacientes')...` y eso traería todo agrupado por especialidades.

Comment: Creo que no me estas entendiendo. Lo que necesito es en la vista poner en diferentes tablas los registros con distintas especialidades. Ya tengo la consulta que me devuelve los datos, lo que quiero hacer ahora es crear una tabla por cada especialidad, y en cada tabla poner los distintos registros.